# MySQL (MariaDB) will not restart after my.cnf change

Tags: mysql, server, centos, mariadb

I changed **my.cnf** to add the **innodb_log_file_size** setting and when attempting to the start the server it fails with the following in the error log:

```
[Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
[Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 10942739155 in ibdata file do not match the log sequence number 11517047974 in the ib_logfiles!
[Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
[ERROR] InnoDB: The page [page id: space=0, page number=7] in file ./ibdata1 cannot be decrypted.
[Note] InnoDB: However key management plugin or used key_version 1 is not found or used encryption algorithm or method does not match.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Ending processing because of a corrupt database page.
InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139948494317824 in file ha_innodb.cc line 21960
```

Below is what is in **my.cnf**:

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/error-log.err
performance-schema=0
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_file_per_table=1
query-cache-type = 1
query-cache-size = 256M
local-infile=0
bind-address=127.0.0.1
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
plugin-load-add=file_key_management
file_key_management_filename=/path-to-key/secret.txt
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm=AES_CTR
innodb-encrypt-tables
innodb-encrypt-log
innodb-encryption-threads = 4
innodb-encrypt-tables=FORCE
innodb-tablespaces-encryption

max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
```

**innodb_fast_shutdown** is set to **1**. Also, I deleted (renamed) both **ib_logfile0** and **ib_logfile1** before restarting. The database uses encryption at rest. Any ideas?

MariaDB version: 10.1.26

Comment: MariaDB has had some bugs related to encrypted tablespaces, for example trying to decrypt a page that is not encrypted (cf. https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10394). You should review bugs and make sure you have upgraded to the latest available version of MariaDB.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it was a bug. I had the database reinstalled as it was but without encryption enabled and changing innodb_log_file_size worked with mysql restarting without any problems.

Comment: Side note:  `query-cache-size = 256M` is dangerously high -- slowing down purges.  Recommend no more than 50M.